# Lambda Calculus vs Category theory in FP

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, lambda-calculus, category-theory

Trying to learn functional programming approach I was faced with both **lambda calculus** and **Category theory** terms.

Could you please explain in layman's terms what are the differences between them, in the scope of FP.

What do they mean for FP?

Thank you!

Comment: Learn lambda calculus first.

Comment: you can take a look at the category theorists' view here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/A%20Categorical%20Manifesto

Comment: also this page has very good insights https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/computational+trilogy

Comment: from https://wiki.haskell.org/Mathematics: Paul Taylor: Practical Foundations of Mathematics. Free online book on mathematics, huge areas of mathematics are described thoroughly, many of them closely related to computer science and functional programming (relational algebra, category theory, Curry-Howard isomorphism). http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pt/Practical_Foundations/index.html

Comment: http://www.paultaylor.eu/~pt/prafm/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to fully answer such a broad question. Below, I tried to provide some insights, but I can not describe these vast topics in only a few paragraphs.

The lambda calculus is the mathematical core of any functional programming language. It can be seen as a very minimalistic programming language, where the key properties of FP can be studied without being distracted by an heavy syntax.

Any programmer, especially if they are FP programmers, should be able to learn the basics of lambda calculus within a few hours of study. Note that, even if the basics are rather simple, the underlying theory is incredibly vast: there's a huge amount of scientific literature dedicated to the lambda calculus. One does not need to know all of this for everyday FP, but reading a few results here and there once in a while can provide some insights on FP. For instance, reading about Church encodings can make one realize how powerful can be a lambda abstraction.

Category theory is one of the most abstract parts of mathematics. Compared with the lambda calculus, it is *much* harder to study. It can be very challenging.

CT is connected with the lambda calculus mostly because it provides a nice way to understand *types*. Types in FP have an underlying algebraic structure which can be best understood by categorical means. For instance, in Haskell the types `(A, Either B C)` and `Either (A,B) (A,C)` are isomorphic (ignoring bottoms, at least;  because *a*(b+c) = (a*b)+(a*c)* ), roughly meaning that they carry the same amount of information. As another example, *currying* and *uncurrying* form the fundamental idea of cartesian closed categories, the "standard" way to interpret simple types.

If you have a programmer's background, you can try Bartosz Milewski's online book [Category Theory for Programmers](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/10/28/category-theory-for-programmers-the-preface/). Still, I would recommend to start from learning some FP and the lambda calculus first.

Comment: "... Any programmer, especially if they are FP programmers, should be able to learn the basics of lambda calculus within a few hours of study ..." Seriously!  Are we talking about Y combinator here.